# why does new emit event syntax give compiler error

Tags: solidity, remix, events

This example returns syntax errors when the emit keyword is used.

```
emit AuctionEnded(highestBidder, highestBid);
```

This is the doc where the example code is.

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/solidity-by-example.html#simple-open-auction

Why are there syntax errors? How do you really call an event in `pragma solidity ^0.4.21;`

Comment: I found two different discussions related to the question, but I don't have any answers.
https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2877
https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3252

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need the correct version of the compiler. `pragma solidity ^0.4.21` is only a hint, but not the selection of the concrete compiler.

If you try this at https://remix.ethereum.org/ which loads the 0.4.21 compiler by default, it will work perfectly fine. When you switch the compiler to a lower version (settings tab), you'll get the syntax error.

Comment: I see, the version was the key thanks! (note etherium.org not com)

Comment: oh.. my fault.. thanks for the pointer, changed it to org.

Answer (score 3):

update truffle

npm install truffle@4.1.5 -g